# Where can I find an online General Relativity course(s)?

Tags: general-relativity, resource-recommendations, education

Not sure if this is the right place to ask, but all well, I will ask anyway...

---

I am hard-pressed with finding an online course that teaches General Relativity in full. I would like to learn General Relativity but I cannot seem to find anything on Google. Is there an online course or courses (free or paid, it doesn't matter to me) that someone can recommend or show me? Maybe it's a University that offers it, and I would be fine with that.

**Note:** I am a beginner to General Relativity.

Comment: @bolbteppa Are those introductory videos to GR or beyond? To be more clear, do they go from beginner level (from the start) to more advanced (towards the end)?

Comment: Hi Compiler v2: Res. recom. qs are restricted on Phys.SE and they usually don't distinguish between online and offline, free or non-free.

Comment: Another book recommendation: "Introduction to General Relativity" (Adler, Bazin, Schiffer, 1975). It is a concise but thorough text on GR. Among other topics, it covers tensor algebra/calculus; Riemannian geometry; relativistic electrodynamics, and the Schwarzschild/Kerr spacetime solutions to the Einstein field equations.

Answer (score 1):

There is one excelent GR course given by Frederic Schuller. It is freely available [on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLFeEvEPtX_0S6vxxiiNPrJbLu9aK1UVC_). He starts from the very basics of topology and differential geometry that are require. These are the first 12 lectures. The other lectures are devoted to GR itself going through the Einstein Field Equations, cosmology, black holes and gravity waves. I think it is quite complete really.

There are plenty of books out there that you can pick to study as you watch the lectures. The two I personally like are [Spacetime and geometry by Carroll](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0805387323) and [General Relativity by Wald](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0226870332).

Wald's book is more advanced. Its advantage is that it goes deeper into things. For instance, I think his discussion of asymptotic flatness is more general and more rigorous than the one given by Carroll in one appendix. Wald's discussion of QFT in curved spacetimes is also more complete.

If you are a beginner I suggest to start with Carroll's book and as you feel the need for a deeper discussion get Wald's book.

Answer (score 0):

Landau & Lifshitz is free online. The volume about field theory treats GR quite well. https://archive.org/details/TheClassicalTheoryOfFields

Comment: You should look further.

Comment: I took a look at the table of contents and it seems to be missing the Einstein Field Equations. Or does it go by a different name in the book? Because I don't see it in there.

Comment: @Compilerv2 Chapter 11 is titled “The Gravitational Field Equations”.